# How to get the numeric characters from the Alphanumeric string in Spark-Sql

Tags: mysql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("select case when length(date)>0  then regexp_extract(date,'\\\\d+', 0) else '' end as date from input").show(false)
```

The above spark code gives the output for the first instance of the numeric characters.

sample input: 1234avf456wef
sample output: 1234456

It should display all the numeric characters from the string. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following modification which uses `regexp_replace` to remove all non-numeric characters.

Below is a working example which also includes removing special characters from `'1234vf456wef &%'`

```
spark.sql("with input as (select '1234vf456wef &%' as date union all select '123' union all select 'a very long 123 string with 456 content.') select date as original,case when length(date)>0  then regexp_replace(date,'[^0-9]', '') else '' end as date from input").show()
```

Outputs

```
+----------------------------------------+-------+
|original                                |date   |
+----------------------------------------+-------+
|1234vf456wef &%                         |1234456|
|123                                     |123    |
|a very long 123 string with 456 content.|123456 |
+----------------------------------------+-------+
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: this query gives the entire string ....not the numerical chars we expect

Comment: @Vikram I've updated the answer with additional samples and the output I received when tested. Can you share the sample and output that did not give you the intended output?

Comment: It works fine now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [REG_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

Maybe you need to adept the regular expression to your needs

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1234avf456wef ', '[a-zA-Z]', '');
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE('1234avf456wef ', '[a-zA-Z]', '') |
> | :----------------------------------------------- |
> | 1234456                                          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=123aa327caacfe9093f8ba8f9f98298b)*

Add the unwanted special characters to the reg string

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1234avf456wef 5§$$§%&"%%', '[a-zA-Z "§$%&/]', '');
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE('1234avf456wef 5§$$§%&"%%', '[a-zA-Z "§$%&/]', '') |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 12344565                                                             |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2bf10006c154563e0d391ee4747a725)*

As you have a string use string functions to cut of at 8 c digits otr pad the string as you need

> ```
> SELECT LPAD(LEFT(REGEXP_REPLACE('1234avf456wef 5§$$§%&"%%', '[a-zA-Z "§$%&/]', ''),8),8,' ');
> ```
>
> ```
> | LPAD(LEFT(REGEXP_REPLACE('1234avf456wef 5§$$§%&"%%', '[a-zA-Z "§$%&/]', ''),8),8,' ') |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 12344565                                                                                 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=214bb1247f02fa8432f0aa37b3764e4c)*

Comment: This works fine Thanks! but what if it the string holds special characters and spaces. In that case , could you alter the query for this too..@nbk

Comment: you can see the changed answer

Comment: That works! Thanks and if I need a another requirement , if i need to check the length of the output should be exactly 8 (i.e) how to check the length in regexp_replace statement.

Comment: regular exprressiondon'T have that, what should happen if the number is lower than 8 padding?

Comment: i added the necessary string functions